# Getting an err status 500 connecting reactmongo to mlabs

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux, mlab

**SOLUTION in the bottom**

i'm trying to connect my reactive spring webflux project to mongodb via mlabs. But from the api and documentation i don't know which method is causing my problem. I set up two methods to work with my mlab db but don't know which should I stick to.

**Method 1** > in the application properties set up my mlab uri

```java
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<fernando>:<password>@ds261277.mlab.com:61277/cont-api?AuthMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
```

i've tried lower case, with & ampersand instead of question mark and adding 
`spring.data.mongodb.database=mycollection`

**Result:** My code runs but when i make any request(get, post, etc) i get an error, adding or removing the "?AuthMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1" doesn't make a difference

```
ERROR 2423 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [eb675923] 500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/content/v1/cont/"


org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='<fernando>', source='cont-api', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='<fernando>', source='cont-api', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
```

**Method 2** > create a dataConfig like so, but when i run, i get an error of trying to connect to local mongodb

```java
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hospitals";
    private static final String  DATABA_URL = "mongodb://<fernando>:<password>@ds261277.mlab.com:61277/cont-api";

    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(new ConnectionString(DATABA_URL));
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);


//    @Bean
//    public ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory(MongoClient mongoClient){
//        return new SimpleReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory(mongoClient, DATABASE_NAME);
//    }
//
//    @Bean
//    public ReactiveMongoOperations reactiveMongoTemplate(ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory database){
//        return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(database);
//    }
}
```

**Results:**

```
[localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
```

any help would be great, thanks in advance

**UPDATE & SOLUTION :**
So i scrapped method two and stuck to method one, i just had to remove the angle brackets from the mlab uri so instead of  it's now //fernando:*password* ...

Comment: please write an answer to your solution so this can be closed

Answer (score 0):

So heads up to anyone using mlab, completely forgot to remove the angle brackets **<   >**

**Before:**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<fernando>:<password>@ds261277.mlab.com:61277/cont-api
```

**After:** without < > around the user and password

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://fernando:password@ds261277.mlab.com:61277/cont-api
```